# What would be the best nearest-neighbor algorithm to use for this application?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, classification, pattern-recognition

I have been classifying multiple objects in a sequence of video frames by taking the the list of ordered centroids of each object in the previous frame and computing the euclidean distance to each set of centroids in the current frame and then taking the minimum distance between a set of points as being the same object in subsequent frames.

This technique works really well, however, I've realized that this is a type of permutation where I am sampling without replacement (once a set of centroids is paired up, they are removed from the list of current centroids). The issue is that there is a possibility that if for a given object a nearest-neighbor is found who might also have another neighbor who is much closer but doesn't get properly paired up because that centroid is now removed from the list of current objects resulting in a misclassification.

Is there something similar to k-nearest-neighbors where I can take into account the other distances from a given centroid that is marked as being the closest neighbor for the current centroid? I apologize if this is confusing, and please let me know if I need to provide an illustration of this particular case. Thanks!

BTW, this is being done in Python, so if there are any appropriate libraries that implement the technique you are suggesting that would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

As I knew, your main question is to optimize algorithm and get better result from classification. In classification problem, depending on your dataset, it is better to try different algorithm with different parameter(for example in NN, try different Nearest Neighbor Number of point or different algorithm like KNN with ball tree or something else) and see the result or evaluate with metrics like cross validation

try look at this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html

you can use Grid Search is sickit for evaluate and test different parameter: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html

or you can use Genetic algorithm to test different parameter and evaluate the result: https://github.com/rsteca/sklearn-deap